# Geting Route params in React Router

Tags: reactjs

In the following snippet

```
 <Route path='/:category' render={() => (
    <div>
       {console.log(...)}
    </div>
 )}/>
```

How can I output the value of the `category` paramater? i.e., with what code do I have to replace the `...` in `{console.log(...)}` ?

```
{console.log(props.match.params.category)}
```

is not working, because `match` is undefined.

Comment: your questions would be more understandable if your title wold be something ilke "...in React Router"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Route path='/:category' render={({match: { params: { category } } }) => (
  <div>
   {console.log(category)}
  </div>
)}/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work: "    'category' is not defined  no-undef"

Comment: The wildcards you specify in the path are available on the `props.match.params` object.
In this case as: `props.match.params.category`
In case the route matches the path

if it's not the case then the problem is caused by something else

Comment: Works. But why is the complicated statement ({match: { params: { category } } }) necessary?

Comment: That way you can use "cateory" inside your code instad of "props.match.params.category" - for some people this is more readable

Comment: It's called object destructuring, it's optional, however quite useful when you returning JSX straight without brackets and return statement. especially if you're using it in multiple places

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <Route exact path={"/:category"} render={(props) => (<div>
       {console.log(props.match.params.category)}
    </div>)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the props for:

> *match.params.category*

Here is an example

```
const Demo = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <p>{match.path}</p>
    <p>{match.url}</p>
    <p>{match.params.category}</p>
  </div>
);
```

And also: [Full example on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/xl6v6k980w)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
<Route path="/:category" render={({match}) => (<div>
       {match.params.category}
</div>)} />
```

Comment: I never had an exact specifier on my route.

Comment: Sorry @user1934212. See the updated answer. Hope that will helps you.!